# "pip install excel2json-3" that Vscode can't detact even I just install it (Vscode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

last time with pandas and json2excel I had the similar problem which I installed again in  the currect directory path  `C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install python-excel2json`then is working,

**but this time even I done the same thing is still Vscode underscore  the function.**

[image: pip install python-excel2json]
[image: pip install excel2json-3]

Comment: you probably user a different python version or a virtual environment in VS Code.

Comment: when I download `python-excel2json` I faced the same problem, I download agian by path `C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install python-excel2json` then is fine. But for installing `excel2json-3` , not works the same.

Comment: so I was wondering if there is other way to solve this